# C++ fread reads random characters at the beginning of the file

Tags: c++, file, fread

I have an input file like;

```
A;Ali;Aksu;N;2;deposit;withdraw
```

and I read it like this;

```
char a[5];
fread(a, sizeof(char), 5, input);
```

But when I try to print

```
cout << a;
```

it writes random characters at first like

```
+^%'A;
```

Comment: What is the file extension and encoding?

Comment: Unicode BOM? .........

Comment: I am kind of new at these stuff actually, so I don't know how to check them

Comment: Get notepad++. That will enable one to store the file as ascii. `od -c` the file as well

Comment: I downloaded notepad++, opened new .txt file and copied input file to the new one and it worked. Thanks. But I couldn't get why this happened.

Answer (score 0):

You need the null character. Change

```
char a[5];
```

to

```
char a[6];
a[5] = 0;
```

If the code is unicode change `char` to `wchar` throughout your code.

Comment: But it adds random characters at the beginning. Shouldn't these random characters be at the end if it is null character? And the lenght of the string changed when I looked it with strlen().

Comment: We do not know the encoding of the file that you have employed?